# Nutch 1.2 No URLs to fetch

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

i have installed cygwin, copied nutch-1.2 inside cygwin directory.

created nutch-1.2/urls/seed.txt with http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk

regex-urifilter has

```
# accept anything else
+^http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/
```

nutch-site has

```
    <configuration>
    <name>http.agent.name</name>
    <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
    </configuration>
```

what am i missing here.

Comment: Can you paste you hadoop.log file? It should give more details on what's happening during the fetch.

Comment: The issue is however i configure proxy, it doesn't seem to be working. Our corporate proxy says invalid credentials.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the proxy in nutch-site.xml?
<property>
  <name>http.proxy.host</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1</value>
  <description>The proxy hostname.  If empty, no proxy is used.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>http.proxy.port</name>
  <value>8888</value>
  <description>The proxy port.</description>
</property>

Comment: I have 2 proxy options, 1 that needs user id/pwd and the other which doesn't need user id/pwd. The one that doesn't need user id/pwd works. Also, i am not sure how to configure urls that don't need to go through proxy and how i can crawl intranet sites.

Comment: What's particular about the intranet site? Can you put the url in the seeds list and crawl it?

Comment: No i couldnt. also how to configure urls to not to go through proxy.